# Windows advanced file matching

Tags: windows, regex, batch-file

I'm trying to use a batch file to list files in a directory such that the file name only (minus extension) matches only numeric patterns, e.g. something like 125646543.pdf which would be easy to express as a regex [\d]+\.pdf but of course I don't have such niceties with Windows-only mechanisms... I'm trying to do this with Windows-only mechanisms since I cannot install anything else on the target servers, and it needs to be supported at least on Windows Server 2000 and 2003.

I'll take a specific solution for this particular example or something more generic that has something more advanced than just ye olde * and ?

I've already tried to work with set /a in order to add a number to the file name, but since it interprets strings as environment variables and 0's if they're not defined, this doesn't work well. I also tried using if %%~na GTR 0, but that matches text file names such as report.pdf as well, since it seems to do a string comparison in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this doesn't belong on serverfault. Cmd.exe may have gotten a bad rap in its early (brain-dead) days but it was still programming even then. And the modern cmd.exe is far more powerful nowadays. It's as much programming related as bash scripts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`findstr` can do regexes under Windows just fine. I'd try:

```
dir /b | findstr /i "^[0-9][0-9]*\.pdf$"
```

The `"dir /b"` gives you the filenames only, one per line. The regex matches one or more digits followed by a period followed by your desired extension. For any extension, you could do:

```
dir /b | findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*\.[^\.]*$"
```

Obviously, if there are other cases more complicated, you can adjust the regex to suit. It doesn't have the full power of UNIX regexes but it's reasonably good.

The following command file shows how you can process each pdf file in the current directory that meets your "all-numeric" requirement.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b ^| findstr /i "^[0-9][0-9]*\.PDF$"`) do (
    set fspec=%%i
    echo.Processing !fspec!
)
endlocal
```

The site http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php is a very good resource for CMD file magic (and many more things).

Comment: The regex in the first example can be simplified if you use the `/i` switch to perform a case-insensitive search: `findstr /i "^[0-9][0-9]*\.pdf$"`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I missed findstr! Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

windows have provided you with an improved programming tool since win98. Its called vbscript.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "c:\test"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileName = strFile.Name
    strExtension = objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile)
    strBase = objFS.GetBaseName(strFile)
    If IsNumeric(strBase) Then 'check if numeric
        WScript.Echo strBase
            'continue to process file here.......
    End If 
Next
```

for more information on vbscript, read the [manual](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=01592C48-207D-4BE1-8A76-1C4099D7BBB9)

Comment: You're absolutely correct, but I have encountered a number of corporate environments where they disabled VBScript/JScript because it was considered to be insecure (whether rightly so or not) so I prefer Pax's suggestion. Thanks much for the suggestion though!

Comment: they are only as secure as the people who use them. with proper controls, ie allowing authorized users the correct permissions, using vbscript is no difference than using batch.

Comment: I totally agree, but I don't make the security policies and the people who do don't necessarily see it the same way. ;]

Answer (score 0):

I pipe dir result to grep :

```
dir [<Drive>:][<Path>] * | grep /regex/
```

Comment: That is a valid answer with today's versions of Windows, but I don't believe would have worked with an out-of-the-box install of Windows Server 2000 or 2003.